# MultipartFile upload comes with one value even if no files has uploaded or selected

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a form that can do upload files. There is a problem when even there is no file selected or uploaded, the size of the value of `@RequestParam` is one which I want it to be empty or null.

Answer (score 0):

According To [this official](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) Mozilla Developer link here is the note regarding input type file.

So just check on backend what is the value for the file parameter by debugging.

> Note: If multiple files are selected, the string represents the first
>   selected file. JavaScript can access the other files through the
>   input's files property. If no file is yet selected, the string is ""
>   (empty). The string is prefixed with C:\fakepath\, to prevent
>   malicious software from guessing the user's file structure.

Comment: by debugging, it does not show anything beside id=xxx, some random numbers. When retrieving the data from the database, the data is the attachment_id of that file. eg, a table that called "attachment" having attachment_id and attachment.